# Azure Machine Learning Experiment Canceled after 10 hours of running

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm working on a deep learning project and I'm using pipelines with an "Execute python script" to run my computations on a private training cluster (**STANDARD_NC12**), which is running on the Enterprise Edition.

It is running correctly, but after ten hours the run is canceled, without an error message or any indication of what happened.

Note that the job status is *Canceled* not *Failed*.

What could cause this? I didn't cancel the job.

Answer (score 0):

a designer pipeline will be canceled if one module cannot finish within 10 hour. For your specific case, I'm not sure why it takes so long. I'd suggest you submit a feedback(the smile face icon on the top right corner) in the Studio portal, the feedback contains some basic trouble shooting info like subscription. Then prod team can follow up.

Comment: Thanks harper !, there is no error message, and the run takes that long because im running a deep learning training on a big dataset, that takes 22 hours